# Unable to set loading indicator with useState hook in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning React and cannot understand why my code isn't working.

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const expensiveFn = () => {
    let z = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      z = i;
      console.log("z", z);
    }
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    console.log("isLoading 1", isLoading);

    setIsLoading(true);
    
    console.log("isLoading 2", isLoading);

    expensiveFn();

    setIsLoading(false);

    console.log("isLoading 3", isLoading);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="">
        <button type="submit" onClick={submitHandler}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>

      {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
    </div>
  );
```

I am not able to get the loading message because the isLoading is not changing.

What am I doing wrong and please, why?

**Update:**
I've combined your answers and tried to change my code accordingly, but now I am getting the state changed, but the message rendered is not displaying.

```
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const expensiveFn = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      console.log("i");
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve();
    });
  };

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      console.log("isLoading", isLoading);
      expensiveFn().then(() => setIsLoading(false));
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="">
        <button type="submit" onClick={submitHandler}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>

      {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
    </div>
  );
```

**Update - 2**
I figured it is the loop that block my render now

**Update - 3**
Thank you for your answers, I wouldn't be able to solve it without you.
I now know(with your help) how to deal with this.

Comment: I think It seems to be invisible because the loop processing speed is fast.  
The code updated in the question works good, and the code I wrote also works too.

Comment: Try changing the loop condition to i < 100000000 .

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in the simplest way, `useState` is asynchronous. Which means, when you call setIsLoading(true), isLoading is not immediately set to true. You should change your expensiveFn to return a promise instead and when that promise is fulfilled, that's when you set isLoading to false.

```
setIsLoading(true);
expensiveFn().then(() => setIsLoading(false));
```

Comment: Thank you. Now my state is changing, but I still can't see my "loading" in the render. I've updated the question.

Comment: @MarkDi saw your update. Your loop should be inside the Promise, not outside.

Answer (score 0):

Because `setState` is an asynchronous function, for checking the state, you can run `useEffect`

[This is a great article on this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/why-is-setstate-asynchronous-in-react-63827033ff45)

Comment: Can you show a working example please? I tried to use useEffect, but it didn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

keyword : setState, setState asynchronous.
reference : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

Fix up code)

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const expensiveFn = () => {
    let z = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      z = i;
      console.log("z", z);
    }
  };

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      expensiveFn();
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form action="">
        <button type="submit" onClick={submitHandler}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>

      {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't show a "Loading..." message. I've tried to combine all the answers and updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

This can seem a bit tricky if you are a beginner, from your code

```
setIsLoading(true);
expensiveFn();
setIsLoading(false);
```

you see, setStates in react are asynchronous and js engine being single threaded the order in which above lines of code executes would be

```
expensiveFn()
setIsLoading(true)
setIsLoading(false)
```

for this reason you would always see `isLoading: false` in console.

solution: You can utilze useEffect hook like this

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(isLoading) {
      expensiveFn()
      setIsLoading(false)
   }
}, [isLoading])
```

Now, expensiveFn() and setIsLoading(false) are only executed after `isLoading` is set to `true`

Comment: Thank you. Now my state is changing, but I still can't see my "loading" in the render. I've updated the question.

Comment: @MarkDi, if you check console, you'll find your code is working as expected, but `Loading...` is not rendered in browser because when `isLoading` is set to `true`, the allocated thread is busy running expensiveFn() and when it finally gets time to execute render(), `isLoading` is already being set to `false`

Comment: if you are trying to simulate network request, i suggest use funcitons like `setTimeout`