# Changing a state and render a component on a function call with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a module where users have to upload images and while waiting I would like to set an overlay with the loading state, I have the following code:

```
const ModulePage = () => {
        
  const sendData = () => {
    //...Send data to firebase
  }
    
  return {
    <div className="Overlay" />  //I want to display this conditionally while sending
      //...
      <button onClick={sendData}>Send Module</button>
  }
}
```

I've tried to use the useState

```
const ModulePage = () => {
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);

  const sendData = () => {
    setIsUploading(true)
    //...Send data to firebase
    setIsUploading(false)
  }

  return {
    {isUploading && <div className="overlay" />} 
    //...
    <button onClick={sendData}>Send Module</button>
  }
}
```

but without useEffect doesn't work and with useEffect it runs on an infinite loop, and if I do this way:

```
const ModulePage = () => {
  const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);
    
  const uploadHandler = () => {
    setIsuploading(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    //...Send data to firebase
    setIsUploading(false)
  }, [isUploading]);
    
  return {
    {isUploading && <div className="overlay" />} 
    //...
    <button onClick={uploadHandler}>Send Module</button>
  }
}
```

it never runs the sendData function

Comment: W/o seeing the code that didn't work it's impossible to guess where you went wrong. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71726032/438992 and so on may help, or searching the web for "react usestate async loading indicator" will likely resolve your issue/s.

Answer (score 0):

if send data code is a promise you try this

```
const sendData = async () => {
  setIsUploading(true)
  await //... Send data to firebase
  setIsUploading(false)
}
```

or this

```
const sendData = () => {
  setIsUploading(true)
  sendDataFunction().then((result) => {
    setIsUploading(false)
  }).catch((err) => {
    setIsUploading(false)
  })
}
```